# Re order issue in for loop R

Tags: r, loops

I am looking to reorder my data into a new dataframe (list in the example below) which the first observation is first, then the last observation is second, both observations are removed from the initial dataframe and then repeat.

```
data <- seq(1,12,1)

i <- 1
ii <- 1:length(data)

newData <- seq(1,12,1)

for (i in ii){
  a <- 1
  newData[i] <- data[a]
  i <- i + 1
  b <- as.numeric(length(data))
  newData[i]<- data[b]

  index <- c(a, b)
  data <- data[-index]

  i <- i + 1
}
```

I receive the error: "Error in newData[i] <- data[b] : replacement has length zero" and the loop stops at i = 8, and the list "data" is empty.

If I run the contents of the loop, but not the loop itself, I get my desired outcome both in this example and my task; but obviously I want to run the loop given the size of my data.

Comment: You are both using `i` as both your `for` loop variable and you are also trying to increment it yourself. You can't do both. If you want to do the adding yourself, rather than a `for` loop, use a `while (i < length(data)) {}` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MrFlick mentioned, you can't modify index in a for loop. But given you only need every second index, you can specify that your loop definition, by using

```
ii <- seq(1,length(data),2)
```

However, you don't need a for loop for rearranging the elements of your vector data. you only need a vector of the form (firs, last, second, secon last, etc.):

```
m = matrix(c(1:6,12:7), ncol=2)
i = as.vector(t(m))
newdata = data[i]
```